# cal4j - Unexpected end of file Exception

Tags: java, ical4j

I have currently no idea what´s here the issue and I asked kindly for help.

I´m generating a ics - File. 
But if I would like to open the ics - File to get the Calender, I got the following error message:

> net.fortuna.ical4j.data.ParserException: Error at line 1:Unexpected end of file

Here my information:
ical4j Version 3.0.1
Java: 8 Build 181

My output from the ics - File:

> BEGIN:VCALENDAR PRODID:-//Ben Fortuna//iCal4j 1.0//EN VERSION:2.0
>   CALSCALE:GREGORIAN BEGIN:VEVENT DTSTAMP:20180826T165052Z
>   DTSTART:01180905T000000 DTEND:01180905T000000 SUMMARY:ddd
>   TZID:Europe/Berlin
>   UID:1535302250819-9ed0489f-0320-4a66-8f9c-4af0e62cdedd END:VEVENT
>   END:VCALENDAR

Here my code for generation the calender.ics - File:

```
public void createEvent(BookingDate bookingDate, Mandatory mandatory, Employee employee)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParserException, ConstraintViolationException {

    // Create a TimeZone
    System.setProperty("net.fortuna.ical4j.timezone.cache.impl", MapTimeZoneCache.class.getName());

    TimeZoneRegistry registry = TimeZoneRegistryFactory.getInstance().createRegistry();
    TimeZone timezone = registry.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin");
    VTimeZone tz = timezone.getVTimeZone();

    String pathMandatoryFile = null;
    String pathEmployeeFile = null;

    // Reading the file and creating the calendar
    Calendar icsCalendar = null;
    FileOutputStream fout = null;

    if (bookingDate.isCreateCalendarMandatoryEntry()) {
        // timezone = registry.getTimeZone(mandatory.getTimeZone());

        pathMandatoryFile = "calendar.ics";
        fout = new FileOutputStream(pathMandatoryFile);
        try {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(pathMandatoryFile);
            CalendarBuilder builder = new CalendarBuilder();
            icsCalendar = builder.build(fin);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        if (icsCalendar == null) {
            icsCalendar = createNewCalender(pathMandatoryFile);
        }
    }

    // Creating an event
    java.util.Calendar startCal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(timezone);
    startCal.set(java.util.Calendar.YEAR, bookingDate.getStartDate().getYear());
    startCal.set(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, bookingDate.getStartDate().getMonth());
    startCal.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, bookingDate.getStartDate().getDate());
    startCal.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, bookingDate.getStartDate().getHours());
    startCal.clear(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE);
    startCal.clear(java.util.Calendar.SECOND);

    java.util.Calendar endCal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(timezone);
    endCal.set(java.util.Calendar.YEAR, bookingDate.getEndDate().getYear());
    endCal.set(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, bookingDate.getEndDate().getMonth());
    endCal.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, bookingDate.getEndDate().getDate());
    endCal.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, bookingDate.getEndDate().getHours());
    endCal.clear(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE);
    endCal.clear(java.util.Calendar.SECOND);

    net.fortuna.ical4j.model.DateTime dtStart = new DateTime(startCal.getTime());
    net.fortuna.ical4j.model.DateTime dtEnd = new DateTime(endCal.getTime());


    String eventName = bookingDate.getName();
    VEvent meeting = new VEvent(dtStart, dtEnd, eventName);

    // add timezone info..
    meeting.getProperties().add(tz.getTimeZoneId());
    String uidValue = bookingDate.getIdHash();
    meeting.getProperties().add(new Uid(uidValue));

    // Add the event and print
    icsCalendar.getComponents().add(meeting);

    CalendarOutputter outputter = new CalendarOutputter();
    outputter.output(icsCalendar, fout);

}


private Calendar createNewCalender(String filePath) throws ValidationException, IOException {

    // Saving an iCalendar file
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

    Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
    calendar.getProperties().add(new ProdId("-//Ben Fortuna//iCal4j 1.0//EN"));
    calendar.getProperties().add(Version.VERSION_2_0);
    calendar.getProperties().add(CalScale.GREGORIAN);

    return calendar;
}
```

Can anybody help me, please.

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the file creation, but rather how you are loading it. For that error I'd suggest checking the file permissions to ensure you are able to read it. Also check file path is correct.

Comment: But than I would expect: FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(pathMandatoryFile); is completly null?

Comment: Yes probably, can't think why else the file stream would end prematurely though.. maybe if you can show the code used to load the file?

Comment: I shared already the code or what do you mean? 
This is causing the issue:   FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(pathMandatoryFile);
            CalendarBuilder builder = new CalendarBuilder();
            icsCalendar = builder.build(fin);

Comment: Ok so it's hard to tell when the input file is created, but if you are creating in another method I'd suggest you haven't properly closed the stream, and would give this error

Comment: Hm, I´m a little bit lost.... what is the following code doing? CalendarOutputter outputter = new CalendarOutputter();
    outputter.output(icsCalendar, fout);

Comment: In this case it writes calendar to a file (some dead code in the other method does nothing), as I said a bit difficult to follow your code. Did you copy/paste examples? Anyway just noticed your input file appears to be missing line breaks, so try to fix the formatting and should solve your problem

Comment: I´ve found this issue: fout = new FileOutputStream(pathMandatoryFile); I have to move it at the end like CalendarOutputter outputter = new CalendarOutputter();
  FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(pathMandatoryFile);
  outputter.output(icsCalendar, fout);   Many thanks